# How can I vertically center a video in a div?

Tags: css

I'm trying to center a video in this div, no matter what height it is. Preferably the solution will not use Javascript.

```
.video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video#bgvid { 
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="video">

<video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">

<source src="assets/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
</div>
```

As of right now, the video re-sizes and stays cut off after 600px height. But it's aligned to the top instead of the center vertically.

Comment: can u provide any kind of screenshot whitch type u want to vertical ?

Comment: I have updated my answer plz check and if you have any query then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this **http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/**

You will get an idea how to set centered vertically.

```
/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Here is

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqKMH)

**Update for video:**

HTML

```
<div id="ex3_container">
   <video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="ex3_content">
     <source src="assets/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #ex3_container { width: 100%;
                   height: 600px;
                   background-color:yellow; 
                   position:relative; }
  #ex3_content { left:50%; 
                 top:50%; 
                 transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
                 -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
                  background-color:gray; 
                  position:absolute; 
                }
```

### [Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/YqKMH/247/)

Comment: Does not seem to work for my video. Maybe because it would be forced off the page if centered?

Comment: @invidious : I have updated my answer. I hope it works for you

Comment: That would center it horizontally (but for some reason, doesn't). I'm looking for vertically.

Comment: @invidious : Now I have corrected. Please change according your requirement. Your basic requirement is fulfilled

Answer (score -1):

#### css

```
.video {
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center; 
}

video#bgvid { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I want it centered vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: hello add  in .video{  text-align : center  }

Comment: hello I want it centered vertically, **not horizontally**.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.